# English dictionary xml/csv file

Tags: xml, csv, dictionary

Does anyone know where I can get a dump of an English dictionary in XML, TXT, CSV format, or something that is easily parseable. I don't need a full dictionary, but I do need individual words and whether each a word is a noun or verb etc.

Anyone knows a location for such a thing?

Thanks.

Comment: All the cool kids use WordNet.

Comment: I don't see where I can download some kind file that I can put in a database from there though?

Comment: http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/standoff-files/core-wordnet.txt

Comment: Here is one I put together. 
https://gitlab.com/joshupetersen/dictionary-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open source dictionaries like GNU aspell will have the words. Not sure about noun, verb, adjective information.

Answer (score 4):

Check this.

http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/

It is the plain text file which can be easily parsed.

It not wordy but very structured.

If you want to extract words and put them into your DB, it is must-check.

Comment: this a great resource but not at all structured.... how can this be used... any idea?

Comment: Someone has done the conversion to csv here:  http://www.bragitoff.com/2016/03/english-dictionary-in-csv-format/